# Confusing output from epubcheck

Tags: xhtml, epub

I'm getting some output from epubcheck that doesn't seem to make sense. I don't understand what the error messages mean and was hoping someone else could help.

The output from epubcheck is:

```
Epubcheck Version 3.0b4

Validating against EPUB version 2.0
ERROR: /path/to/my/book.epub/sub_html_file.html(134,117): text not allowed here; expected element "td" or "th"
```

then there are hundreds of other messages. Line 134 of the offending file looks like

```
<hr class="calibre29"/>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="calibre53">
   <tr class="calibre56"> 1
     <td class="calibre55" valign="top">
      <p class="calibre30"><span class="calibre21"><strong class="calibre8">Person(s)</strong></span></p>
      </td>
```

What confuses me is that position 117 of that line starts `td`, which is what `epubcheck` is saying it requires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple XHTML validation error. If you look at your HTML (I've reformatted it slightly), you will see that your `<tr>` element contains text as well as element content. That's not allowed. The content model for `<tr>` contains only `<th>` and `<td>`, nothing else.

You need to wrap that '1' in an element.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not an expert at HTML so I didn't know what the message meant.

Comment: No problem. I'm not a great fan of the output of epubcheck myself. It would be good to be able to get context for a start

Comment: The message meant, uhhh, 'text not allowed here; expected element "td" or "th"'. I can't imagine a clearer message. It even gave you the character position on the line in question. For context, it's not hard to set up your favorite editor/IDE to automatically parse these error messages like any other build/compile error, and jump right to the file/line in question.